# How to JMX monitoring Tomcat6 with zabbix 3.4

Tags: tomcat6, jmx, zabbix

I've been trying to monitor a server with Tomcat6 thanks to JMX probe of a zabbix server.

On the zabbix server side there is: zabbix-server3.4 / zabbix-java-gateway
On the Tomcat server side there is: zabbix-agent / tomcat6

---

Configuration of the zabbix_java_gateway.conf:

```
LISTEN_IP="11.11.150.99"
START_POLLERS=5
```

---

I saw on some tutorials that I add to modify the configuration of the catalina.sh file so I replaced:

```
CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS $JPDA_OPTS"
```

with

```
   CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS\
                -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote \
                -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=11.11.150.152 \
                -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=10052 \
                -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false \
                -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false \
                -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=11.11.150.152"
```

---

Host with Tomcat6 to monitor (let's call him T6): 11.11.150.152
OS: Ubuntu 10.01.4 LTS

The host configuration of T6 on the Zabbix server:

```
Agents: Zabix Agent is enable, SNMP too, JMX is red:" cannot connect to [[11.11.150.152]:10052]: [111] Connection refused"
```

Configuration of T6:

```
Name: T6
Agent interface: 11.11.150.152:10050 -working (green)
Agent interface: 11.11.150.152:161 -working (green)
Agent interface: 11.11.150.152:10052 -not working (red)
```

Configuration of Zabbix Server:

```
Name: Zabbix server
Agent interface: 11.11.150.99:10050 -working (green)
```

---

I tried to debug with tcpdump using:
tcpdump -i eth0 host 11.11.150.99 and port 10052
and I get:

```
14:01:11.365982 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 32717, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    zabbix.eco.local.34636 > sva2.eco.local.10052: Flags [S], cksum 0x0224 (correct), seq 1624311701, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 23820376 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
14:01:11.366002 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    sva2.eco.local.10052 > zabbix.eco.local.34636: Flags [R.], cksum 0x55c7 (correct), seq 0, ack 1624311702, win 0, length 0
```

So they are communicating but T6 kind of reject my zabbix server request.

What do I miss?

---

UPDATE:
I changed the port in the catalina conf file to 12345.
Now I get this error message:

java.io.IOException: Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 11.11.150.152; nested exception is: 
java.net.ConnectException: Connexion refusée (Connection refused)]

---

My JMX interface is: [IP] 11.11.150.152 [PORT] 12345

Comment: What are your JMX interface details ?

Comment: JMX interface: [IP] 11.11.150.152 [Port] 12345, do you need something else? I really want to make it works

Comment: But in your Tomcat config, you said you had `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=10052`. You should match your JMX interface port with whatever Tomcat listens on, and make sure you can actually reach that port from your Zabbix server (or Java gateway) system.

Comment: I changed it and specified it in both JAVA_OPTS & CATALINA_OPTS (I don't which one I have to use). Still got the same error message. How can I make sure that I can reach it? There is no iptable or selinux on it

Comment: First, check whether Tomcat listens on the port you configured. Then, check the TCP connection to that port (telnet is the easiest method usually). Then, check the access with a CLI tool like `jmxterm`. If all that works, then it becomes a Zabbix question :)

Comment: Tomcat won't listen to the port I configured , and so I can't telnet... Where should I specify to Tomcat to listen on a specific port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this chinese man tutorial and enjoy!

http://www.justfbt.com/2015/10/28/Monitoring-tomcat-By-zabbix/

Comment: The link seems to be dead